# How to make specific link static?

Tags: ros, simulation, gazebo, urdf

I want to simulate a RR robot in gazebo and I want to place the first link over a box. This box shouldn't be a part of the simulation, and is there only for visual effect.

**How can I make a specific link/object static?**

I created a fixed joint with a link named "world". Also, I tried adding a static tag.

However, it still included in the physics calculations, resulting in a weird behaviour. It spins on its own and it tilts, like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Relevant parts of the urdf:

```
<link name="world"/>

<joint name="world_joint" type="fixed">
  <parent link="world"/>
  <child link="base_link"/>
  <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 ${base_height}"/>
</joint>

<link name="base_link">
  <visual>
    ...
  </visual>
  <collision>
    ...
  </collision>
  <inertial>
    <mass value="100" />
    <inertia ixx="0.1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
              iyy="0.1" iyz="0.0"
              izz="0.1" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 ${-base_height/2}"/>
  </inertial>
</link>

<gazebo reference="base_link" >
  <material> Gazebo/Blue </material>
  <static>true</static>
</gazebo>
```

I made the inertia of the base_link greater

```
<inertia ixx="100" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="100" iyz="0.0" izz="100" />
```

and now the base doesn't tilt and the link doesn't rotate on its own. However, as I specified it as a static link, I anticipated that it shouldn't have that behaviour no matter its inertia.

**Edit**
After some more searching, i found out that you cannot specify a link as static ([sdf documentation](http://sdformat.org/spec?elem=link)). However, i still expect that the fixed joint with the world frame would keep the box in place.

I also changed some parameters of the physics engine, namely erp and cfm (you can find them [here](http://www.ode.org/ode-latest-userguide.html#sec_3_5_0)), but the weird behaviour continued.

Comment: Have you tried removing inertia and collision settings altogether? If it's just a visual then try it with only the visuals.

Comment: I tried it, and now the gazebo gui doesn't load any model. I anticipated that, as the inertial information are required according to [this](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_urdf&cat=connect_ros)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a static link, you add the the kinematic property to your urdf:

```
<gazebo reference="base_link" >
  <!-- other properties you want to define for the base link -->
  <kinematic> true </kinematic>
</gazebo>
```

[Here](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.9&elem=link#link_kinematic) is a list of the properties of links. There isn't a static property. There is a *kinematic* property. I found this [source](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/25064/kinematic-property-of-link/) that said the following:

> A kinematic link (as opposed to a dynamic link) is not affected by external forces. It can influence other bodies in its vicinity, but it's not influenced by them.

And i tested it and it worked perfectly.

[image]